# npm install mongodb error

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

I get the following error when I try to install the nodejs mongodb driver:

```
(precise)me@localhost:~$ sudo npm install mongodb
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mongodb

npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: mongodb
npm ERR!     at /usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/get.js:139:12
npm ERR!     at cb (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:31:9)
npm ERR!     at Request._callback (/usr/share/npm/lib/utils/npm-registry-client/request.js:136:18)
npm ERR!     at Request.callback (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:119:22)
npm ERR!     at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:212:58)
npm ERR!     at Request.emit (events.js:88:20)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/request/main.js:412:12)
npm ERR!     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:67:17)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1261:11)
npm ERR!     at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
npm ERR! You may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://bugs.debian.org/npm>
npm ERR! or use
npm ERR!     reportbug --attach /home/me/npm-debug.log npm
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Linux 3.8.11
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! cwd /home/me
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.12
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.4
npm ERR! message failed to fetch from registry: mongodb
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/me/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
(precise)me@localhost:~$
```

I am running ubuntu 12.04 on a chromebook (via crouton) with a 32 bit processor.

Comment: Does the log add anything? Urm, you are using a MASSIVELY old version of Node.JS!

Comment: node 0.6.12 so yea pretty old. I guess apt-get is not up to date for node.

Comment: I've added an answer on how to upgrade Node the "right" way for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your installation of Node.JS is a long way out of date, you should start by updating to at least Node v0.10.x

The recommended approach for Ubuntu 12 uses the [NodeSource PPA](https://nodesource.com/blog/nodejs-v012-iojs-and-the-nodesource-linux-repositories) that is an extension of Chris Lea's PPA.

Upgrading Node.JS will also upgrade NPM. When you've done that, retry the MongoDB install. I'm currently running that library on a number of different platforms and it works fine.